# Custom Icons from file in addKML from leaflet.extras package

Tags: r

I'm trying to add custom icons from file on an internet restricted computer. When I create an Icon via https: it does not work because of restriction to the internet: (On a regular computer this code works fine)

```
airportsIcon <- makeIcon(
    iconUrl = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/airports.png"
)

leaflet() %>%
    setView(-77.0369, 38.9072, 12) %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
    addWebGLKMLHeatmap(kml, size = 20, units = "px") %>%
addKML(
    kml,
    markerType = "marker",
    markerIcons = airportsIcon
)
```

If I try to load the icon from file:

```
greenLeafIcon <- makeIcon(
   iconUrl = "C:/Documents/airports.png"
)
```

It works for the leaflet package addMarkers() function, but it does not work for the addKML() function above.  Am I missing something?